# Ajax - return results based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropdown

I am trying to get a dropdown to change results on a page using Ajax. I have it working using a simple text link but I cannot get it to work using a dropdown.

I have tried adding:

```
if ($('.myclass').change
```

and

```
$('.results').on('change','.myclass', function (e) {
```

I am unsure how get the value from the dropdown or what needs to be changed to use a dropdown.

This is the working code using a simple a href:

```
if ($('.myclass').length) {
    var paginate = function (url) {
        var param = '&ajax=1',
            ajaxUrl = (url.indexOf(param) === -1) ? 
                       url + '&ajax=1' : 
                       url,
            cleanUrl = url.replace(new RegExp(param+'$'),'');

        $.ajax(ajaxUrl)
            .done(function (response) {
                $('.results').html(response);
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.results').offset().top
                });
                window.history.pushState(
                    {url: cleanUrl},
                    document.title,
                    cleanUrl
                );
            })
            .fail (function (xhr) {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
            });

   }
$('.results').on('click','.myclass a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    paginate(url);
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    if (e.state.url) {
        paginate(e.state.url);
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};        
}
```

Comment: For select boxes / dropdown, it should be: `$('.results').on('change', function(){ // Code here... });`

Comment: Are you using dropdown from something like bootstrap or you are calling HTMLSelect a dropdown?

Comment: could post html code and explain more your issue

Comment: or `$('.results').change(function(){ ...})` to get the value in that function you can do `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your select mark up is like this:

```
<select name="" id="test">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
```

Your jquery can target it using:

```
<script>
$("#test").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
$("#test").on('change', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

**Edit**

For what it's worth your don't need to use preventDefault() on the dropdown like you would on the link, however this probably wouldn't cause an issue.